# Como testar um método que depende do resultado de outro com JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, testes, testes-de-unidade, junit

Saudações,

Tenho uma classe que faz ações em um email. Criei alguns testes para essa classe e gostaria de saber se essa é uma forma válida de teste ou se existe alguma forma melhor de fazer isso.

Eu testo a leitura de emails e depois testo mover mensagens de uma pasta para outra, porém as mensagens que vão ser movidas dependem da leitura. Portanto eu preciso chamar o método de leitura dentro do método de movimentação também para que possa mover pelo menos uma mensagem. O ideal seria Mockar o Array de Message?

> Estou aperfeiçoando meus estudos em testes ainda, portanto fiquem a vontade para críticas e sugestões

Segue abaixo a classe de testes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("teste")
public class EmailTest {

    ReadEmail readEmail = new ReadEmail();
    MoveMessages moveMessages = new MoveMessages();

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailTest.class.getSimpleName());

    @Test
    public void readEmail() {
        Message[] messages = new Message[0];

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(readEmail, "usuario", "usuario");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(readEmail, "senha", "senha");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(readEmail, "host", "host");

        try {
            messages = readEmail.read();
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(e.getMessage().contains("!! ERRO AO CAPTURAR AS MENSAGENS"));
        }

        assert Objects.nonNull(messages);
        Assert.assertTrue(messages.length > 0);
        Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.stream(messages).anyMatch(message -> {
            try {
                return InternetAddress.toString(message.getFrom()).contains("@domain.com.br");
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Erro ao buscar remetente");
            }
            return false;
        }));
    }

    @Test
    public void moveEmail() {

        Message[] messages = new Message[0];

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(readEmail, "usuario", "usuario");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(readEmail, "senha", "senha");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(readEmail, "host", "host");

        try {
            messages = readEmail.read();
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Erro ao capturar mensagens para serem movidas: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        assert Objects.nonNull(messages);
        assert messages.length > 0;

        Message[] messagesParam = new Message[1];
        messagesParam[0] = messages[0];

        try {
            moveMessages.move("Inbox", "teste", messagesParam);
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(e.getMessage().contains("!! ERRO AO MOVER AS MENSAGENS"));
        }

        // ASSERTS ...
    }


}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Você possui os seguintes contextos de teste: 1) Testar read 2) Testar o move 3) Testar os dois integradamente. Para você testar o move, você não precisa ler as mensagens, basta prover um mock de `messagesParam` e realizar as verificações necessárias nos mocks. Para o read a mesma coisa. Agora para o teste integrado, você deve no mesmo teste ler e mover, não em testes separados

Comment: Mas se eu mockar os dados no `read` como vou saber se a busca realmente funciona? Eu estou trazendo as mensagens do meu email. E no `move` a mesma coisa. Tudo bem, eu posso até mockar uma mensagem real do meu email, nesse caso, mas se um dia eu apagar essa mensagem por exemplo, o meu teste deixa de funcionar pq ele não vai mais localizar a mensagem no email para move-la.

Comment: Ai que está a questão, só faz sentido você prover um mock se você está realizando testes unitários para verificar apenas o `read` e apenas o `move`. Para o teste integrado você deveria prover uma mensagem na caixa para ser `read`, depois realizar o `move` no mesmo teste, sem mock algum

Comment: Então não faz sentido nenhum eu testar o método `read` se for parar pra pensar. Pq ele simplesmente vai até a caixa de email e traz todas as mensagens de um determinado remetente. Meu teste se baseia em ver se ele realmente traz essas mensagens. Se eu vou mockar as mensagens, não tem o que testar desse método. Correto?

Comment: O que há nas classes `ReadEmail` e `MoveMessages`?

Comment: As classes são grandes, mas a `ReadEmail` busca os emails não lidos de um email filtrando por um remetente específico. A classe `MoveMessages` move os emails lidos e filtrados pela `ReadEmail` para uma pasta diferente. Precisa dos códigos ?

Comment: Então, o spring tem anotações para que você crie mocks e simule o comporatamento [Essa é a documentação dos Mocks do Spring.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) <- Ali tem exemplos de utilização. :D

Comment: A ideia do teste unitário é testar uma única coisa: se todo o resto funcionar, esse trecho específico também funciona? Para simular "todo o resto funcionando", usa-se mocks. Se for testar só o `read`, basta verificar se o retorno tem as mensagens corretas. Se for testar só o `move`, o `read` faz parte de "todo o resto", então ele deve ser *mockado* (aí vc pode criar vários cenários: uma lista com várias mensagens, uma lista vazia, etc). Se quer testar duas funcionalidades (read + move) trabalhando em conjunto, não é mais um teste unitário: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741845

Comment: @YuriZamboni @hkotsubo Perfeito, eu entendi que o ideal é mockar as mensagens. Mas imaginem que eu mock uma mensagem para o `move` move-la. Caso essa mensagem não exista no email, ele retornará erro, certo?? O meu método `move` depende das mensagens válidas que o meu read traz. Então eu não poderia deixar esse teste no código. Não sei se deu pra entender o cenário que estou imaginando.

Comment: Bom, o teste unitário não deveria ler os emails de uma inbox "oficial"/de produção/real (assim como um teste unitário não deveria acessar o banco, nem chamar serviços em URLs reais em outras máquinas, etc), ele deveria rodar de forma isolada, sem dependências externas. Vc deveria ter uma inbox *mockada* (que se comporta como se fosse real), aí você pode manipulá-la à vontade, sem precisar que existam emails na inbox real. Assim vc não depende de fatores externos e ainda pode criar vários cenários (inbox vazia, com vários emails, etc). Se quer testar com emails reais, não é mais unit test...

Comment: @hkotsubo Entendi. Mt obrigado !